# Angular, where is data stored?

Tags: angular, typescript

Stupid question I was thinking about.

If I create for exampe a resolver and the data is fetched from the server - where is it stored? How does Angular know that my data is put inside an "thisIsMyDataVariable"?
And is there some kind of "garbage collector" that cleans it all out when my component is destroyed?

I cant find any details on this

Comment: Are you talking about data being held in components? When you say to put data inside a variable, where is this variable scoped?.

Comment: Yes, data being held in components, how does it basically works? Is it "just javascript"? Earlier I could store some data in a hiddenfield directly in the markup - but here i just have a variable inside my component which sits on the client - where is that stored?
I guess I need some basic javascript knowledge? :D

Comment: Can you post an example of code you don't fully understand? It is highly probable your question is a duplicate, so its already answered elsewhere.

Comment: Very basic example  

items: any[];    

this.myService.getData()  
         .subscribe(items => this.items = items);  

How is this stored? My question might not make any sense at all - but im just trying to understand how the framework/browser persist the data

I mean - if we dont talk about scopes etc, then i could store my data as json in a hiddenfield and then get the data back same way.. that i can understand :D But how is this being stored?

Comment: Make your example larger and explain exactly what parts don't you understand by editing the question instead.

Comment: sorry, not sure how to make line breaks - hope i can read my code anyways.. I put my "items" into my items variable and then it gets stored there? Why would i ever store something in a hiddenfield then? because it persists throgh postbacks in asp.net webforms?

Comment: @lilezek - Kevin said: Every component has its own scope so its data is stored in a json object with that section of html.. If this is how it works, can you help me with an example?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23030073/1531971